# Why my web project with added x86_x64 Tridion's dlls does not work properly on my local 32bit machine?

Tags: content-delivery, configuration, dd4t

**Scenario:**

- I have 32 bit dev-machine and 64 bit server
- The project's target is **AnyCPU**
- My local project works perfectly with x86 dlls from Tridion. **But this requires to enable 32bit support in my AppPool.**

**I just want to minimize the configuration stage and the option 32bit support to stay disabled.**

- For this reason I deleted Tridion's dlls(x86) from my /bin and added new Tridion's dlls(x86_x64).

**And then I run my project locally I received the error:**
*Could not load file or assembly 'Tridion.ContentDelivery.AmbientData' or one of its dependencies. An attempt was made to load a program with an incorrect format.*

When, or if, this issue is fixed then I will try to copy the project on my 64bit server and and try with AppPool with disabled 32bit support.

**If I change back the the x86 dlls the project works fine.**

Any suggestions?

**Thanks in advance.**

Comment: The difference between your 32-bit dev machine and 64-bit server might be justification for an upgrade, yeah? ;-) If so, we gathered some options when working with a *64 bit development machine* in this [SO question](http://stackoverflow.com/q/11789245/395495), mainly using a 64-bit "version" of Cassini or using IIS to debug.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This isn't an 'answer', but thought it would be a good place to share this link which contains a bit of information about the 32/64 3rd party libraries:

http://www.tridiondeveloper.com/tridion-content-delivery-deployment-errors-unable-to-load-dll-xmogrt-and-system-badimageformatexception

Answer (score 6):

That's the way it is. Some of Tridion's x64 DLLs run only on 64 bit servers/app pools. If the only difference in your webapps is the Tridion DLLs, then I think that should be manageable, no?

Unfortunately, I don't think there's much you can do about it (or Tridion) since some of those DLLs are unmanaged code (and from a 3rd party too).